# Including a class in a method of another class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress plugin, OOP-style.
Creating tables in the admin interface the native way requires extending another class.

`myPlugin.php:`

```
class My_Plugin {

    public function myMethod(){
        return $somedata;
    }

    public function anotherMethod(){
        require_once('anotherClass.php');
        $table = new AnotherClass;
        $table->yetAnotherMethod();
    }

}
```

`anotherClass.php:`

```
class AnotherClass extends WP_List_Table {

    public function yetAnotherMethod(){
        // how do I get the returned data $somedata here from the method above?
        // is there a way?

        // ... more code here ...
        // table is printed to the output buffer
    }

}
```

Comment: Just call the method! The method is `public`, therefore it is available in the sub class!

Comment: `$table->yetAnotherMethod($this->myMethod())`; ??

Comment: @BenCarey `AnotherClass` is not a derived class of `My_Plugin`

Comment: @BartFriederichs I noticed this and corrected it in my answer. The question is not worded particularly well!

Answer (score 1):

As `myMethod()` isn't static, you'll need an (the?) instance of `My_Plugin` to get that info:

```
 $myplugin = new My_Plugin();

 ....

 $data = $myplugin->myMethod();
```

Or, you supply that info to the `yetAnotherMothod` call:

```
 $data = $this->myMethod();
 require_once('anotherClass.php');
 $table = new AnotherClass;
 $table->yetAnotherMethod($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `$somedata` into your function call. For example

```
$table->yetAnotherMethod($this->myMethod());

public function yetAnotherMethod($somedata){
    // do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `myMethod()` method is public, so therefore can be accessed anywhere. Make sure you include all necessary files like so:

```
require_once('myPlugin.php')
require_once('anotherClass.php')
```

Then simply write something like this:

```
// Initiate the plugin
$plugin = new My_Plugin;

// Get some data
$data = $plugin->myMethod();

// Initiate the table object
$table = new AnotherClass;

// Call the method with the data passed in as a parameter
$table->yetAnotherMethod($data);
```